# twython search string limit with twitter api : results missing

Tags: python, twitter, twython

Hello I am super new to coding, still in the phase, copy paste, learn, change some variables, run, cross fingers, bang fist or raise fist...etc.

I have created a twitter bot using [this tutorial](http://www.silkstream.net/blog/2014/06/retweeting-with-your-twython-twitter-bot.html)

my code is as follows

```
import time
from twython import Twython, TwythonError

app_key = "xxxx"
app_secret = "xxxx"
oauth_token = "xxxx"
oauth_token_secret = "xxxx"


naughty_words = [" -RT"]

good_words = ["search phrase", "another search phrase", "yet another", "one more", "search phrase two", "TFW search phrase"]


filter = " OR ".join(good_words)

blacklist = " -".join(naughty_words)

keywords = filter + blacklist

twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

search_results = twitter.search(q=keywords, count=100)
try:
for tweet in search_results["statuses"]:
    try:
        twitter.retweet(id = tweet["id_str"])
        except TwythonError as e:
        print e
except TwythonError as e:
print e

time.sleep(300)
```

so when i run the code it sometimes get results and it retweets them, but if i run the code with just two of the search terms it finds more and retweets them.

i dont know if i am over the twitter search api limit (which i found several different numbers for) or the string of OR OR OR OR is messed up or too long.

any advice for python and the twitter api is welcome. many thanks

EDIT: A UTF-8, URL-encoded search query of 500 characters maximum, including operators. Queries may additionally be limited by complexity.

even with the OR and spaces i am still not over the limit.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) for reference. You don't specify what you mean by "it finds more". Anyway, I'd say your problem could be that you are using phrases instead of words. In a twitter query, a space between two terms is an AND. If you search with "term1 term2 OR term3 term4 OR term5...." it will actually start combining ANDs and ORs and I don't know what it will end up doing. Note that in the tutorial you provide, it uses words, not phrases. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much,  yes not very precise at all sorry

when i reduce the search terms, the app returns and thus retweets more results, when i search for the full string nothing is retweeted.

like i said i thought it was possible that maybe there was some confusion with the OR OR OR.

in the tutorial provided however she does specify a phrase as one of the search terms, 

i thought the phrases were isolated so it would search for :

"term1 term2" OR "term 3 term 4" OR "term 5 term 6"

 is there a way of seeing what twython is querying to twitter to see "what it will end up doing?"

Comment: Hi. You are right, there are some phrases in the tutorial you provide. Well, sometime in the past I got some problems when trying to combine ORs with phrases (which implicitly include ANDs) and that's why I mentioned. By the way, `twython` does not touch the query you compose, it just sends it to twitter. If I get some time today I'll try to investigate your example and if I find out anything I'll post an answer.

Comment: hey thanks for writing back

i think i solved the problem by using %22 instead of the quotation marks.  many thanks


good_words = ["%2this is one phrase%22", "%22this is another%22"]

Comment: Thanks! Even if it is your a question, please post it as an answer, and accept it (I think you have to wait one day to accept it). This way, it will be a reference for others having the same problem (e.g. myself sometime in the future). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i solved the problem by using %22 instead of the quotation marks. many thanks

good_words = ["%2this is one phrase%22", "%22this is another%22"]